# Index out of range using input dim 1 in loss function using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I write code in tensorflow using convolution neural network to read street view house numbers (SVHN) data.

first thing, I **store the label for each image in an array**, **then** I read each image with its array label using **TFRecords**. for example::

I store the label for image that contain 5348 address like this [4,5,3,4,8,0]. index one related to the number of digits in the address(image), and the last number related to no digit in this index which means that there are images has 5 digits not four, and sometimes have three or two.

In layers step. I used 5 fully connected layer, I do not know exactly(in details) why I should do that but I know that each logit for each digit in label. Then I summation the loss function for each logits

```
   logits1 = fully_connected(network, 10, weights_init='xavier')  #activation='softmax'
   logits2 = fully_connected(network, 10, weights_init='xavier')
   logits3 = fully_connected(network, 10, weights_init='xavier')
   logits4 = fully_connected(network, 10, weights_init='xavier')
   logits5 = fully_connected(network, 10, weights_init='xavier')


   loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits1, labels= labels[:,1])) +\
                          tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits2, labels= labels[:,2])) +\
                          tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits3, labels= labels[:,3])) +\
                          tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits4, labels= labels[:,4])) +\
                          tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits3, labels= labels[:,5]))
```

the error is::

> tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits4, labels= labels[:,4])) +\
>
> ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [2], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1>.

***EDIT:::***

[the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwis85cil3gfkdz/SVHN_v5.py?dl=0) --> it is work just with fixed number of digits for each address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to slice a 1D `tensor` using 2D index. Following code would work, also you may need to rethink the logics.

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits1, labels= labels))                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits2, labels= labels)) +\
     tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits3, labels= labels)) +\
     tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits4, labels= labels)) +\
     tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits3, labels= labels))
```

Comment: you may consider to get label as `2D tensor` then, otherwise it won't work.